# How to get Swagger support for a mostly MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project, where the controllers mostly return views. I do have a small number of action methods that act as API endpoints returning various things.

I am having trouble wiring in Swagger support. By default, it says

> No operations defined in spec!

which is correct since none of the controllers have the `[ApiController]` attribute on them. If I do add this attribute, it complains that my non-API endpoints do not have an attribute route.

So, is it possible to wire in Swagger support into a controller with mostly MVC endpoints?

PS: I know I can extract all API calls into a separate api controller, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: You should do that. Having an endpoint that can have non-idempotent behavior is a dangerous precedent, especially when using a standardization technology like Swagger.

Comment: I agree, even if just from the single-responsibility principle alone. Adding `[ApiController]` engages a whole slew of functionality not intended for MVC endpoints. I wouldn't even put APIs in the same project as MVC. The scaling and other needs could be vastly different.

Comment: Agree with all points above.  But this is a relatively small project.  Was hoping to keep things simple.  But yeah, will do some refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

In fact,you don't have to add `[ApiController]` attribute on the controller,

You got the error

> No operations defined in spec!

just because it couldn't read  paths from `[Route]` attribute to generate a json file accord with OpenApi specification

I tried as below in program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();


builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

else
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
        options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();




app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();



app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

The result:
[image]

[image]